# Why event listeners execute the following code?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I built this code as part of udemy AJAX course. I'd appreciate your takeaway about why my event listeners execute the `console.log` code before they get clicked, and the console logs the correct answer 4 times (named a) as part of `ansChecker` function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Ajax</title>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Trivia api</h1>
  <div>Score: <span id="score"></span></div>
  <div id="output"></div>
  <div id="selAnswers"></div>
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Next Question">
  <script>
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', getItem);

    var answers = {
      'correct': 0,
      'incorrect': 0
    };

    function getItem() {
      var url = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1";
      var output = document.getElementById('output');

      requestAjax(url, function(data) {
        var info = data.results[0];
        console.log(info);

        output.innerHTML = '<div>Category: ' + info.category + '</div>';
        output.innerHTML += '<div>Question: ' + info.question + '</div>';

        questionBuilder(info.correct_answer, info.incorrect_answers);
      });
    }

    function questionBuilder(corr, incorr) {
      /*console.clear();*/

      var holder = incorr;
      
      holder.push(corr);

      holder.sort();

      var selAnswers = document.getElementById('selAnswers');

      for (i in holder) {
        //                selAnswers.innerHTML ='';
        selAnswers.innerHTML += '<input type="button" id="answer" value="' + holder[i] + '">';

        document.getElementById('answer').addEventListener('click', ansChecker(corr));
      }
    }

    function ansChecker(a) {
      console.log(a);
    }

    function requestAjax(url, callback) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
          callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        }
      }

      xhr.open('GET', url, true);

      xhr.send();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following line executes the `ansChecker` function, instead of passing it through to the event listener as a callback:

```
document.getElementById('answer').addEventListener('click', ansChecker(corr));
```

The parameter should be binded or called within the callback function, like so:

```js
// Within callback example
document.getElementById('answer').addEventListener('click', () => ansChecker(corr));

// Binded example
document.getElementById('answer').addEventListener('click', ansChecker.bind(this, corr);
```

In general, MDN is a good place to read on the parameters expected and has good examples to get you going:

AddEventListener:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Bind:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

---

For your second question, it consoles `Counter-Strike` 4 times due to the target the event listener is attached to:

```js
document.getElementById('answer');
```

This will attach the event listener on the first element it finds with the id `answer` and in this case it would always be the Counter Strike input. Also, an `id` should be unique for the whole page DOM, so don't re-use the same one. There are different ways to target the individual elements for each answer. One way would be to do the following:

```
holder.forEach(value => {
    let inputEl = document.createElement('input');
    inputEl.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    inputEl.setAttribute('value', value);
    selAnswers.appendChild(inputEl);
    inputEl.addEventListener('click', () => ansChecker(corr));
});
```

Comment: Thanks @m.spyratos.